# How do you set directory permissions in NSIS?

Tags: windows, installation, permissions, nsis

I'm trying to build a Windows installer using Nullsoft Install System that requires installation by an Administrator. The installer makes a "logs" directory.  Since regular users can run this application, that directory needs to be writable by regular users.  How do I specify that all users should have permission to have write access to that directory in the NSIS script language?

I admit that this sounds a like a sort of bad idea, but the application is just an internal app used by only a few people on a private network.  I just need the log files saved so that I can see why the app is broken if something bad happens.  The users can't be made administrator.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the [AccessControl](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) plugin and then add this to the script, where the "logs" directory is in the install directory.

```
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\logs" "(BU)" "FullAccess"
```

That gives full access to the folder for all users.

Answer (score 19):

`AccessControl::GrantOnFile "<folder>" "(BU)" "FullAccess"` didn't work for me on a Windows Server 2008 machine. Instead I had to use this one:

`AccessControl::GrantOnFile  "<folder>" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "FullAccess"`

S-1-5-32-545 is equivalent to "Users" according to [Microsoft Support: Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems).

Answer (score 10):

Instead of changing the permissions on directories under Program Files, why not put the logs in a location that is writeable by all users.

See the 4.9.7.7 SetShellVarContext section in your NSIS documentation. You can use it with $APPDATA to get the application data folder that is writeable for all users.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for how to accomplish this in log4net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468989/how-to-specify-common-application-data-folder-for-log4net/1889591#1889591

Answer (score 6):

It's an old issue now but as suggested by Sören APPDATA directory is a nice way to do what you want, the thing is :
Don't take user's personnal APPDATA but the "All Users" APPDATA dir!
This way anyone will be able to access the log file ;-)

Also, I read somewhere that using (BU) on the GrantOnFile is not working well with some systems (Win 7 x64 if I remember well), maybe you should use the SID "(S-1-5-32-545)" instead (it's the All Users' SID, this value is a constant on each Windows OS)

Answer (score 5):

One way: call the shell, and use [`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) or [`xcacls`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754).

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a log-directory in the user's %APPDATA% directory? Do you really need to put all the logs in the install directory? Why?

Comment: I want other users to be able to view the logs too.  If they are in the users APPDATA directory, then if user 1 runs the app, only user 1 or an admin can see the log file.