# How to specify common application data folder for log4net?

Tags: logging, log4net, environment-variables

I want log4net to write log files (using RollingFileAppender) to a subfolder of the common application data folder (e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Company\Product\Logs).
However, on Win XP, there is no environment variable that specifies this folder. We have `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`, we have `%APPDATA%`, but there is nothing like `%ALLUSERSAPPDATA%`.
Programatically, I could use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`, but I need to put it in the log4net config, something like this:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value="%ALLUSERSAPPDATA%\Company\Product\Logs\error.log" />
</appender>
```

OK, we could define this in our setup, but maybe someone comes up with a better idea?

Comment: please correct the question title spelling "specifiy"

Comment: Per the link in @codeulike's answer, as of 1.2.11, you can simply use a PatternString expression like [`%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c/1535998#1535998).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This posting](http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=110142086820117&w=2) on the log4net mailinglist explains how you can define your own path replacement variables.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the right idea. I will define a property and use a PatternString for the folder in the config file.

Comment: You can use solution from accepted answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically/1535998#1535998 . This solution is working on Win Xp and all folowing systems

Comment: Can you summarize the main ideas from the link?

Comment: Link-only answer can use any value once the link goes dead. Please summarize the solution provided in that linked resource.

Answer (score 35):

We just use this:

```
<param name="File" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/Company/Product/Logs/error.log"/>
```

It works great.

---

This line can simply be inserted into your current appender configuration:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <param name="File" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/Company/Product/Logs/error.log"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: This solution will not work on Win Xp, since there is no valid resolving for ${ALLUSERSPROFILE}. Solution for all systems (Win Xp and following) is in accepted answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically/1535998#1535998

Comment: In Windows XP, ALLUSERSPROFILE does exist and defaults to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users, so this should work, unless you have a permissions issue.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the full code from the log4net mailing list that [pilif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468989/how-to-specifiy-common-application-data-folder-for-log4net/469017#469017) linked to:

Basically the method is to implement a custom pattern converter for the log4net config file.

First add this class to your project:

```cs
public class SpecialFolderPatternConverter : log4net.Util.PatternConverter
{
    override protected void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        Environment.SpecialFolder specialFolder = (Environment.SpecialFolder)Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), base.Option, true);
        writer.Write(Environment.GetFolderPath(specialFolder));
    }
}
```

Then set up the File parameter of your FileAppender as follows:

```xml
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
    <converter>
      <name value="folder" />
      <type value="MyAppName.SpecialFolderPatternConverter,MyAppName" />
    </converter>
    <conversionPattern value="%folder{CommonApplicationData}\\SomeOtherFolder\\log.txt" />
</file>
```

Basically the `%folder` tells it to look at the converter called `folder` which points it to the SpecialFolderPatternConverter class. It then calls `Convert` on that class, passing in the CommonApplicationData (or whatever) enum value.

Apparently in the next release of log4net (1.2.11) there will be a simpler method, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c/1535998#1535998).

Comment: how to use this converter(which I also found in log4net official site but did not succeed) in `<param name="File"` section(in which @pduncan mentioned)

Answer (score 4):

In the current log4net version (2.0.8.0) you could simply use

`<file value="${ProgramData}\myFolder\LogFiles\" />` for `C:\ProgramData`

`${LocalAppData}` for `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\`

and `${AppData}` for `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\`

Answer (score 3):

Complete and working solution - content of my Log4net.config file. In actual version of Log4Net there is no need for writing own pattern converter anymore

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}\\MyProject\\Logs\\log.txt" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <ConversionPattern type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%%-5p %%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %%m%%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Tried this, it just created a goofy folder with a percent in it under my web application.

Answer (score 1):

Now (in 2018 FEB) as per log4net version 2.0.8.0.

You can use without any converter to get Environment Variables as follows.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}\\mylogfile.txt" />
```

Refer: [log4net.Util.PatternString](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm) class documentation for more details.

Comment: %env{LOCALAPPDATA} and not %envFolderPath{LOCALAPPDATA} worked for me.