# C# how to specify the appData file path in the app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I am using log4net and I was to save the log file in the AppData file for win XP/Vista etc.

This is my app.config file so far, and I have specified the name softphone.log. Hoewver, I am not sure how to specify the complete path to the file as each user will have a different path depending on their username.

```
<log4net>
    <logger name="default">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="softphone.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackup value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

In my source code I can get the path by doing the following:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

However, I can't use the above in my app.config and if I hard coded the path on my system the path would be:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\John\Application Data
```

However, this would be different for each client. So is there a way to do this for the app.config file?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify common application data folder for log4net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468989/how-to-specify-common-application-data-folder-for-log4net)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't believe that you can do what you want, there is a method for custom parsing areas of the app.config file so that you could add your own token that you could replace with the correct value, but I don't see how that would work inside the log4net section.

However, everything that is set up for log4net inside the config can also be set in code. I think you're best option would be to set the property for the appender in code just after application start.

---

Ahh, never mind a quick search has revealed my ignorance. From [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.566751.6) and [here](http://malor.se/blog/?p=23) it appears that something similar to this:

```
<file value="${APPDATA}\log-file.txt" />
```

Will do what you want. I haven't tested this myself, so I'll leave my first answer up too - but I'd be interested to know if you have any luck with it.

Comment: Glad you edited ;) There's always a way of getting to the environment variables somehow.

Comment: I will give it a try and report back with my results. Thanks.

Comment: Just to say that this works okay for me, I've only tested it under XP at the moment, but I assume it works on Vista also.

Comment: Both links are dead :( I tried figuring out a new link for both, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

User %appdata%.
So your code will look like -

```
<file value="%appdata%/softphone.log"/>
```