# %LOCALAPPDATA% dosen't work in app.config

Tags: c#

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="1">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="%LOCALAPPDATA%\DBLog\application.log">          
          <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Verbose"/>
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

How does I solve the problem with %LOCALAPPDATA% not working in my app.config, I need to able to configure inside a xml file. Not in the code if possible. It's the

Answer (score 2):

Please try this ${LOCALAPPDATA}

Comment: @4thex which .net verison ?

Comment: My comment was about using it inside system.diagnostics. It will not resolve an environment variable inside the initializeData attribute. The .NET Framework version I am using is 4.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

> %LOCALAPPDATA% dosen't work in app.config

It doesn not seem to work. See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964132/c-sharp-how-to-specify-the-appdata-file-path-in-the-app-config-file) or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b22d805-6712-4035-905b-8109675432a2/how-to-customize-tracelistener-file-location).

I suggest you the following:

- If you wanna use the `${VARIABLE}` syntax you should try [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial). There is a great tutorial on codeplex.
- Else you have to expand your environment variables and create your trace
  listeners in code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to modify your code to this :

```
initializeData="${LOCALAPPDATA}\DBLog\application.log"
```

Comment: <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="${LOCALAPPDATA}\TCT Mapping\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>