# Is there a way to configure Log4Net to write the logs to the BaseDirectory in a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services, log4net

Logs in a Windows Service are not written to the path of the exe because the windows service is started in another directory. What's the best way to write the logs to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory?

This is my appender:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <!--<file value="Logs/Log4Net/"/>-->
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd-HH.lo\g"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I have found a way to set it dynamically in code, but no way to set it right in the xml configuration...

Comment: Why do you want to write the log file in the installation folder? Usually these folders are more restricted (for a reason) then some application data folders.

Comment: Where would you write the logfile? Just C:\Logs\...?

Comment: By the way, you're right, the folder is so restricted that log4net can't even write to the folder. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only elevated accounts can write in the installation directory.

You have to log in applictation data folder instead. Check this:

[How to specify common application data folder for log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468989/how-to-specifiy-common-application-data-folder-for-log4net)