# common location of log file in log4net not working?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have an issue with the location of log file in log4net.

I gave this node for the location to create the log file

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\MyProject\error.txt/>
```

As I think it should create the log file in user folder. But this one is creating in the

```
bin\debug\ALLUSERSPROFILE\MyProject\error.txt
```

Even I tried `AppData` also but its behaving the same.
Am I doing any mistake??

Is it required any converter to convert environment variables?

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468989/how-to-specify-common-application-data-folder-for-log4net

Comment: No... I saw that but it couldn't helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Apache log4net file appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#FileAppender)

> This example shows how to configure the file name to write to using an environment variable TMP `<file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use it as follows:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\MyProject\error.txt/>
```

Comment: No... it created a (ALLUSERSPROFILE) folder in bin\debug and writting logfiles in that

Comment: I think we need to change ALLUSERSPROFILE to USERSPROFILE