# log4j2 writing in file when testing, not when deploying

Tags: maven, jax-rs, log4j2

I'm building a web service using jax-rs and wanted to log some stuff when urls are called. I found about log4j 2 and decided to use it.
I dont know why but it works when I do some tests

```
Response response = target("user/v1/"+alfred.getPseudo()).request().get();
assertTrue(response.getStatus() < 300);
```

This will put the log String in logs/logs.log (I love logs).
Yet, when I deploy (with glassfish 4.1.1), it doesn't write a single char in the file when I call the same URL.

Here's my `log4j2.xml` (located in src/main/resources) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
       <File name="File" fileName="logs/logs.log">
           <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}[%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My `web.xml` is empty :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

I have the lo4j-api and log4j-core, both 2.5, in my pom.xml.

Finally, here's the code :

```
private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

on which I just call `logger.info(String)` and `logger.error(String)`.

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to create logs when deploying ?

Thanks.

**EDIT :** Perhaps this will help. I previously had

```
<File name="File" fileName="logs/logs.log" bufferedIO="false">
```

When I was testing, I had a warning "Hey, you set bufferedIO to false but the default buffer size is 8192, wtf". And this warning was being shown when i was calling the urls during real deployment. I guess that means my configuration was detected when deploying aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I understood my mistake from this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486370/5670024

I was trying to write the file inside the application's directory.
Changed

```
<File name="File" fileName="logs/logs.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}[%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
```

to

```
<File name="File" fileName="c:/logs.log">
     <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}[%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
```

and it works !

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the location in `web.xml`, I suppose.

`<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`

Please check the deployment for the location of `log4j2.xml` and change the `param-value` accordingly.

But it is recommended to use a `log4j2.xml` at WAR level. So it is easy to find and change.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunatly, putting the xml file in `WEB-INF/classes` and adding the context-param you gave in `web.xml` didn't do it. It no longer works with test (I guess that might be normal), and still don't add any line in `logs.log`