# NSIS Access Control Read Only

Tags: nsis

I have a C program with an installer created by an NSIS script. The issue is one of the files that the installer adds needs to be read only. For this problem I am trying to use the AccessControl plugin. I include the plugin directory with the following line:

```
!addplugindir "AccessControl\Unicode\Plugins"
```

At the bottom of my install section I have attempted these lines with no success:

```
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\file.txt" "BUILTINUSERS" "GenericRead + Delete"
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\file.txt" "(BU)" "GenericRead + Delete"
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\file.txt" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "GenericRead + Delete"
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\file.txt" "(S-1-1-0)" "GenericRead + Delete"
```

There is no error displayed when the script is compiled but after running the installer the file can still be written over. I have had no success from any of these sources.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in

http://avidinsight.uk/2014/01/nsis-access-control-problem-with-built-in-users-group/

[How do you set directory permissions in NSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116876/how-do-you-set-directory-permissions-in-nsis)

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk:AccessControl_plug-in

On a final note I am using Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GrantOnFile` appends to the existing ACL for the file and never restricts anything. Use `SetOnFile` to start a new ACL or in your case, use `DenyOnFile` to deny access for specific groups.

You should also `Pop` after each call to these functions, the popped string will be "ok" or a error message.